# Is it possible to set more than one cookie with a single Set-Cookie?

Tags: http, cookies

One HTTP Set-Cookie directive can only hold one cookie, is it right? I mean, one single `name=value` pair?

Comment: Since you say directive, are we talking about htaccess or something?
If so the tags should be redefined.

Using javascript you can set however many cookies you please.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The original cookie specification of Netscape (see [this cached version](http://web.archive.org/web/20020803110822/http://wp.netscape.com/newsref/std/cookie_spec.html)) does not say anything about listing multiple cookie declarations.

But as of *Set-Cookie* as defined by [RFC 2109](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2109) allows a comma separated  list of cookie declaration:

> Informally, the Set-Cookie response header comprises the token Set-Cookie:, followed by a comma-separated list of one or more cookies. Each cookie begins with a NAME=VALUE pair, followed by zero or more semi-colon-separated attribute-value pairs.

The same applies to *Set-Cookie2* as defined by [RFC 2965](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2965):

> Informally, the Set-Cookie2 response header comprises the token Set-Cookie2:, followed by a comma-separated list of one or more cookies. Each cookie begins with a NAME=VALUE pair, followed by zero or more semi-colon-separated attribute-value pairs.

But since most user agents still follow Netscape’s original specification, I would rather suggest to just declare each cookie with its own *Set-Cookie* header field.

This is also what the latest [RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265) reflects:

> Origin servers SHOULD NOT fold multiple Set-Cookie header fields into
> a single header field.  The usual mechanism for folding HTTP headers
> fields (i.e., as defined in [RFC2616]) might change the semantics of
> the Set-Cookie header field because the %x2C (",") character is used
> by Set-Cookie in a way that conflicts with such folding.

Comment: The last specification is RFC6265, which doesn't say anything about several cookies in a single Set-Cookie header, as far as I can see: http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265.txt

Comment: I can confirm that Google Chrome has highly unusual parsing when you try to send multiple cookies, so it's certainly not advisable.  It perplexed me for a great while on how to parse the cookie according to RFC 2109 since the "," character as a cookie separator does indeed make it basically impossible to parse.  So, to put it simply, you just don't parse it.

Comment: "But since most user agents still follow Netscape’s original specification" - is this still the case? Tried sending multiple cookie in one header today and it didn't work ... at least in chromium