# Is there a way to retrieve http header "Set-Cookie" in one line?

Tags: http

I am trying to parse access logs from Zeus web server but I noticed that "Set-Cookie" header for the response will contain \r\n line feed for multiple cookies.

```
Set-Cookie: cookie1=1-2; domain=.google.com; path=/; expires=Wed, 10-May-2017 07:14:05 GMT\r\n
Set-Cookie: cookie2=1-2; domain=.google.com; path=/; expires=Wed, 10-May-2017 07:14:05 GMT\r\n
```

This separates a single hit/access into multilines and makes it harder to parse the log. Is there a way to combine this into single line through HTTP protocol? Or is this a webserver-specific functionality?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to set more than one cookie with a single Set-Cookie?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880047/is-it-possible-to-set-more-than-one-cookie-with-a-single-set-cookie)

Comment: I took a look at the link. So "Set-Cookie2" is what I want.. but most browsers don't seem to support it. Is that the correct understanding?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately... Maybe you need to change your parse code to deal with multiple `Set-Cookie` issue.